# Trying to requery an already closed cursor - what's wrong?

Tags: android, cursor

My app throws an error:

```
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {app.piotrek.learning/app.piotrek.learning.AddNewQuestion}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40f7f8a8
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1183)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40f7f8a8
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4508)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
11-08 17:19:40.800: E/AndroidRuntime(18592):    ... 10 more
```

Error seem to show up when I go to another activity and I tap "back button".
I've already found out that problem is somewhere here:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    db = new Database(getApplicationContext());

    db.open();

    fillSpinner(db.getAllEntriesSubjects(), spinnerSubject, DatabaseData.KEY_NAME);
    //long data = spinnerSubject.getSelectedItemId();
    //Log.v("ADDNEWQUESTION", "Wybrano: " + data);
    //fillSpinner(db.getAllEntriesTitles(), spinnerTitles);
    db.close();
}

public void fillSpinner(Cursor cs, Spinner spinner, String dane){
    startManagingCursor(cs);

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cs, new String[] {dane}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

AFAIK, I don't close any Cursor. What's wrong then?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `db.close();` from the `onResume` method and add it to the `onPause()` method.
Hope it helps.

Comment: So, what should I do if I want to run onCreate() after tapping "back button"? How to kill Activity when I am in another one?

Comment: You should't kill your activity, is better move the necessary code to onStart() or onResume(). To kill an Activity use finish() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

public void onBackPressed() {

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddNewQuestion.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    super.onStop();

}
```